# What lubricant can be used for mechanical parts in a system containing diethyl ether?

Tags: solubility, ethers

I make a **thermal actuator** that works with the expansion of diethyl ether at its boiling point of around 34 °C. For sealing and lubrication of the polypropylene piston and barrel, I need **a lubricant that is immiscible with diethyl ether and does not react with it**.

I found that diethyl ether is slightly soluble in water, and that it dissolves oils. I suppose this means that many of the everyday oil- and water-based lubricants are not fit for this application (as diethyl ether will dissolve in the lubricant)?

**Any other suggestions for a lubricant that can be used here?**

Comment: Let me ask: can't you consider another liquid with low boiling point, other than ether? Diethyl ether is a great solvent, and anything that comes to my mind (oils, silicone, etc) are soluble in it.

Comment: Thanks. An alternative would be N-pentane (boiling point 36 °C), which apparently is insoluble in water, but which is a little bit harder to obtain. Would it be possible to super-saturate a water-based lubricant to minimize dissolution of diethyl ether in it?

Comment: Solid lubricants, such as graphite and molybdenum disulfide might reduce friction, and are not soluble, *but* might *not* help sealing... you'd need to test.